# Unable to connect to a specific wifi network (WPA2 Enterprise)

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, wicd, wpa2

My computer is able to connect to other networks, but for some reason I am unable to connect to a specific one (gives bad password error). I am using Wicd Network Manager.

I think it might be a configuration issue and was wondering if there was any files I should be aware of that may contain bad information for this connection. I had the same issue on the default ubuntu network manager which was one of the main reasons I tried switching to Wicd (after attempting to update the old one).